# Safely extract zip or tar using Python

Tags: python, zip, tar, tarfile, python-zipfile

I'm trying to extract user-submitted zip and tar files to a directory. The documentation for zipfile's [extractall](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) method (similarly with tarfile's [extractall](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractall)) states that it's possible for paths to be absolute or contain `..` paths that go outside the destination path. Instead, I could use `extract` myself, like this:

```
some_path = '/destination/path'
some_zip = '/some/file.zip'
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(some_zip, mode='r')
for subfile in zipf.namelist():
    zipf.extract(subfile, some_path)
```

Is this safe? Is it possible for a file in the archive to wind up outside of `some_path` in this case? If so, what way can I ensure that files will never wind up outside the destination directory?

Comment: Starting with python 2.7.4, the method [`zipfile.extract()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.extract) prohibits the creation of files outside the sandbox. So, this method is now safe as of python 2.7.4. The vulnerability still exists for tar archives, however.

Answer (score 45):

**Note:** Starting with python 2.7.4, this is a non-issue for ZIP archives. Details at the bottom of the answer. This answer focuses on tar archives.

To figure out where a path really points to, use `os.path.abspath()` (but note the caveat about symlinks as path components). If you normalize a path from your zipfile with `abspath` and it does *not* contain the current directory as a prefix, it's pointing outside it.

But you also need to check the *value* of any symlink extracted from your archive (both tarfiles and unix zipfiles can store symlinks). This is important if you are worried about a proverbial "malicious user" that would intentionally bypass your security, rather than an application that simply installs itself in system libraries.

That's the aforementioned caveat: `abspath` will be misled if your sandbox already contains a symlink that points to a directory. Even a symlink that points within the sandbox can be dangerous: The symlink `sandbox/subdir/foo -> ..` points to `sandbox`, so the path `sandbox/subdir/foo/../.bashrc` should be disallowed. The easiest way to do so is to wait until the previous files have been extracted and use  `os.path.realpath()`. Fortunately `extractall()` accepts a generator, so this is easy to do.

Since you ask for code, here's a bit that explicates the algorithm. It prohibits not only the extraction of files to locations outside the sandbox (which is what was requested), but also the creation of links *inside the sandbox* that point to locations outside the sandbox. I'm curious to hear if anyone can sneak any stray files or links past it.

```
import tarfile
from os.path import abspath, realpath, dirname, join as joinpath
from sys import stderr

resolved = lambda x: realpath(abspath(x))

def badpath(path, base):
    # joinpath will ignore base if path is absolute
    return not resolved(joinpath(base,path)).startswith(base)

def badlink(info, base):
    # Links are interpreted relative to the directory containing the link
    tip = resolved(joinpath(base, dirname(info.name)))
    return badpath(info.linkname, base=tip)

def safemembers(members):
    base = resolved(".")
    
    for finfo in members:
        if badpath(finfo.name, base):
            print >>stderr, finfo.name, "is blocked (illegal path)"
        elif finfo.issym() and badlink(finfo,base):
            print >>stderr, finfo.name, "is blocked: Symlink to", finfo.linkname
        elif finfo.islnk() and badlink(finfo,base):
            print >>stderr, finfo.name, "is blocked: Hard link to", finfo.linkname
        else:
            yield finfo

ar = tarfile.open("testtar.tar")
ar.extractall(path="./sandbox", members=safemembers(ar))
ar.close()
```

**Edit:** Starting with python 2.7.4, this is a non-issue for ZIP archives: The method [`zipfile.extract()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.extract) prohibits the creation of files outside the sandbox:

> **Note:** If a member filename is an absolute path, a drive/UNC sharepoint and leading (back)slashes will be stripped, e.g.: `///foo/bar` becomes `foo/bar` on Unix, and `C:\foo\bar` becomes `foo\bar` on Windows. And all `".."` components in a member filename will be removed, e.g.: `../../foo../../ba..r` becomes `foo../ba..r`. On Windows, illegal characters (`:`, `<`, `>`, `|`, `"`, `?`, and `*`) [are] replaced by underscore (_).

The `tarfile` class has not been similarly sanitized, so the above answer still apllies.

Comment: You can assume the new sandbox directory is empty

Comment: I thought as much; but you still need to watch out for the exploit I outlined: First the archive contains a symlink to another directory, then a file that uses the symlink as its path.

Comment: realpath will convert the extracted file into its real path, so you could probably just check that after extraction?

Comment: Right, you can use `realpath` to test every symlink immediately after extracting it (which means you can't use `extractall` to unzip the archive, since you need to check after extracting each file).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've awarded you the bounty, but I'll leave the question unanswered for now, just because this is tar-specific. The zipfile module doesn't have methods to tell whether a file is a symlink.

Comment: This really should be supported by default :/

Comment: According to the readme, `Archive.extract()` will raise an exception if it detects an out-of-bounds file. The exception will terminate the bulk extraction, and there's no way to resume it. There doesn't even seem to be a way to list the archive contents and extract one file at a time. Color me unimpressed.

Comment: I think the print messages for symlinks and hard links should be swapped.

Comment: Oops, good catch @Alb

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to the popular answer, unzipping files safely is not completely solved as of Python 2.7.4.  The extractall method is still dangerous and can lead to path traversal, either directly or through the unzipping of symbolic links.  Here was my final solution which should prevent both attacks in all versions of Python, even versions prior to Python 2.7.4 where the extract method was vulnerable:

```
import zipfile, os

def safe_unzip(zip_file, extract_path='.'):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as zf:
        for member in zf.infolist():
            file_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(extract_path, member.filename))
            if file_path.startswith(os.path.realpath(extract_path)):
                zf.extract(member, extract_path)
```

**Edit 1:** Fixed variable name clash. Thanks Juuso Ohtonen.

**Edit 2:** `s/abspath/realpath/g`. Thanks TheLizzard

Comment: Avoid using `zipfile` as parameter name since it conflicts the import name: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ZipFile'`.
Fix is to rename `zipfile` parameter to e.g. `zip_file`.

Comment: Thanks, for the comment.  I fixed the sample code.  I originally grabbed it out of my project and edited it to be stand-alone and clearly forgot to test it.

Comment: Why are you using `os.path.abspath` not `os.path.realpath`? Wouldn't it be more safe to use `os.path.realpath`?

Comment: Good point.  I'll update the answer to reflect that suggestion.  `realpath` apparently calls `abspath`, so `realpath` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ZipFile.infolist()`/`TarFile.next()`/`TarFile.getmembers()` to get the information about each entry in the archive, normalize the path, open the file yourself, use `ZipFile.open()`/`TarFile.extractfile()` to get a file-like for the entry, and copy the entry data yourself.

Comment: This seems really tricky to make sure I get right - especially if you have files like ``../../../../subdir/../../something/file.txt`` - where should the destination be? No one has made code available to deal with this before?

Comment: No one can answer that for you, since only you understand your application requirements.

Comment: I disagree. Other tools do this automatically for you - for example the ``tar`` command automatically gets rid of absolute paths unless you specify ``--absolute-names``.

Comment: And any software that delegates to `tar` has to abide by that. This is **your** software.

Comment: *sigh* When you come across an entry with an invalid/disallowed path you have 3 options: 1) attempt extraction anyway, and catch any errors 2) extract to a modified path 3) don't extract. *I can't tell you which policy is appropriate for your application.*

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Sure but why doesn't Python give you those options? It clearly could. And why is the *default* option pretty clearly the absolute worst?

Answer (score 3):

Copy the zipfile to an empty directory. Then use `os.chroot` to make that directory the root directory. Then unzip there.

Alternatively, you can call `unzip` itself with the `-j` flag, which ignores the directories:

```
import subprocess
filename = '/some/file.zip'
rv = subprocess.call(['unzip', '-j', filename])
```

Comment: The subprocess module works on every platform that runs Python, AFAICT. But if you are talking about MS Windows, There are several programs for handling zipfiles available for it, like INFO-zip. The specific command line would of course need to be adapted for the program you wish to use.

Comment: You're right, `os.chroot` is specific to UNIX. But if you search for them you'll find chroot like applications for windows. Of course the real overkill solution in this case would be to run `unzip` in a virtual machine. :-)

Comment: That's a brilliantly simple idea, but (a) it only really works on Unix systems, and (b) on Unix, only the superuser can chroot. Privilege escalation in the midst of dealing with potentially unsafe data is really the wrong way to go...

Comment: Using the `-j` flag of info-zip's `unzip` as an alternative of chroot should work on any platform that unzip works on.

Answer (score 2):

## **PSA: The accepted answer to this question is out of date!**

As of Python [release 3.11.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#notable-changes-in-3-11-4) there is an extraction filter mechanism included in [tarfile.TarFile.extractall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractall). This mechanism, when using the `data` filter, will ensure safe extraction of tarballs in most cases (including [CVE-2007-4559](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2007-4559)).

If you have the ability, you should use a version of python >=3.11.4 when processing untrusted tar files so as to avail yourself of the provided security features. The accepted answer should be implemented iff you can't use the language feature for this purpose.

fair thee well fellow exhausted engineer...