# How can I read a compressed folder file using python?

Tags: python

I can use `gzip` to compress a single file, but I can not use it to compress a folder. I used this:

```
tar = tarfile.open("TarName.tar.gz", "w:gz")
tar.add("folder/location", arcname="TarName")
tar.close()
```

The folder was compressed, how can I uncompress it? Or is there any other methods to compress a folder? By the way, please add the way to uncompress. Thanks very much

Comment: I think you will have to take some approach like in this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1855118/2548351.

Comment: @caiohamamura Thanks very much, I will have a try.

Comment: Are you trying to *uncompress a `.tar.gz` file* ?

Comment: @KevinGuan The codes I wrote was I found on a web, I do not why it is `.tar.gz`, what I want is to compress/uncompress a folder. Now I am still trying some other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to open the tarfile and extract:

```
import tarfile

with tarfile.open("TarName.tar.gz") as tar:    
    tar.extractall()
```

Everything you need to know is provided in the extensive [examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#examples) in the documentation.
If you are worried about external files you can take one of the approaches from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060069/safely-extract-zip-or-tar-using-python)

Comment: thanks very much, I get the right answer from your code.

Comment: [``extractall`` is dangerous](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractall) and should *not* be used with untrusted input.

Comment: @JonasWielicki, if the OP is creating the file what is the issue? They asked for a way to uncompress which is what extractall is doing and what is used in the documentation examples

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I thought I’d mention it in case someone looks at this question in the future who did not create the files. Also we do not know how the OP is processing the files, e.g. whether they are transmitted automatically over untrusted paths or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Conversely, you can use `tarfile` library to open `tar.gz` archives.
For that, you can use the mode `r:gz`.

Python documentation has a section about data compression and archiving that you might like: https://docs.python.org/2/library/archiving.html

For folders, zip and tar.gz module are the two available modules in the standard library.

Last, I recommend you to have a look to the capacity of `with` statements on open/close patterns.

Comment: yes you are right , `with` is a better choice on open/close patterns.

Comment: I have read the `docs`, but to be honest, I did not find the way to compress/uncompress folder.